# Animation query in framer motion

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I have made an animation in which the text appears after some delay. I want to do the same thing after some time so that the the animation disappears (the reverse of the incoming). I have no clue on how to do that.

```
import React from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

const animationVariants = {
  initial: {
    x: '-100%', // Offscreen left
  },
  animate: {
    x: 0, // Move to the center
    transition: {
      duration: 1, // Animation duration
      type: 'tween', // Type of transition
      ease: 'easeInOut', // Easing function
    },
  },
};

const childAnimationVariant = {
  initial: {
    x: '-200%',
  },
  animate: {
    x: 0,
    transition: {
      duration: 1,
      type: 'tween',
      ease: 'easeInOut',
    },
  },
  exit:{
    x:"-200%",
    transition:{
        duration:1
    }
  }
};

const stagger = {
  animate: {
    transition: {
      staggerChildren: .7, // Delay between each child element
      delayChildren:1,
    },
  },
};

const Preloader = () => {
  return (
    <motion.div
      initial="initial"
      animate="animate"
      variants={animationVariants}
      className="w-full h-screen bg-black absolute top-0 left-0 flex justify-center items-center"
    >
      <motion.div variants={stagger} className="text-white flex flex-col gap-10">
        <motion.h3 variants={childAnimationVariant} className='text-9xl'>Web Developer</motion.h3>
        <motion.h3 variants={childAnimationVariant} className='text-9xl'>UI/UX Designer</motion.h3>
        <motion.h3 variants={childAnimationVariant} className='text-9xl'>Freelancer</motion.h3>
      </motion.div>
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default Preloader;
```

Answer (score 0):

youcan use keyframes

```
  <motion.div
      initial={{ x: "-100%" }}
      animate={{ x: ["-50%", "50%", "50%", "50%", "150%"] }}
      transition={{ duration: 2, delay: 2 }}
    >
      شيييييش
    </motion.div>
```